# How to check for POSIX-conformance with autoconf

Tags: posix, autotools, autoconf

My project follows the **POSIX.1-2008** standard and I would like to ensure that the user's implementation conforms to this standard.

So far I've been using `AC_DEFINE` to define the [`_POSIX_C_SOURCE`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_02_01) macro as specified in the POSIX standard.

```
AC_DEFINE([_POSIX_C_SOURCE], [200809L], [Define the POSIX version])
```

However, since this is a simple C preprocessor `#define` macro , it does nothing to prevent an implementation that *isn't* POSIX-compliant from compiling.

Does **Autoconf** offer a standard macro to check for the implementation's conformance to a specific POSIX standard?

Comment: Perhaps this collection of [Pre-defined Compiler Macros](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) will be useful; in particular the [standards](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Standards/) page

Comment: [`The <unistd.h> header shall define the following symbolic constants. The values shall be suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives.`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html) This is a pretty reliable alternative if Autoconf has no specific macro: **POSIX.1-2008** requires the definition of `_POSIX_VERSION` set to `200809L` in the *unistd.h* header file. So I can just test for the existence and value of `_POSIX_VERSION` -- but how do I do this portably in *configure.ac*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To portably check if the user's implementation conforms to a specific POSIX standard, use [`AC_EGREP_CPP`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Running-the-Preprocessor.html#Running-the-Preprocessor) to check the existence and value of `_POSIX_VERSION`:

```
AC_EGREP_CPP(posix_200809L_supported,
             [#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
              #include <unistd.h>
              #ifdef _POSIX_VERSION
              #if _POSIX_VERSION == 200809L
              posix_200809L_supported
              #endif
              #endif
             ],
             [],
             [AC_MSG_FAILURE([*** Implementation must conform to the POSIX.1-2008 standard.])]
)
```

This works due to several guarantees made by POSIX.

---

### Step 1

We first set `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to `200809L`.

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

**POSIX.1-2008** states that when an application includes a header described by **POSIX.1-2008**, and when this feature test macro (`_POSIX_C_SOURCE`) is defined to have the value `200809L`, then [`all symbols required by POSIX.1-2008 to appear when the header is included shall be made visible`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_01_01).

---

### Step 2

So when we include `unistd.h` in the next line, *all* symbols required by **POSIX.1-2008** to appear in `unistd.h` will be made visible.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
```

Since [`_POSIX_VERSION`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html#tag_13_77_03_01) is required to appear in `unistd.h`, it too is now visible.

---

### Step 3

`_POSIX_VERSION` is required by the **POSIX.1-2008** standard to be [set to a value of `200809L`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html#tag_13_77_03_01).

> For implementations conforming to POSIX.1-2008, the value shall be 200809L.

So all we have to do now is test if `_POSIX_VERSION` is defined, and if so, whether it's set to a value equal to `200809L`.

```c
#ifdef _POSIX_VERSION
#if _POSIX_VERSION == 200809L
```

Checking whether `_POSIX_VERSION` is defined helps us determine if there is support for any **POSIX** standard on the implementation. Checking the value of `_POSIX_VERSION` helps us narrow down whether a specific version of the **POSIX** standard is supported.

If both of these conditions are true, then the implementation almost certainly supports **POSIX.1-2008**.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an autoconf test that relies on the negative array size trick:

```
  AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
    [[#include <unistd.h>]],
    [[int n[(_POSIX_VERSION == 200809L) ? (-1) : (+1)];]])],
    AC_MSG_FAILURE([POSIX.1-2008 profile required]))
```

Using `getconf` is fine if the software is only being built on the host machine.

```
ac_posix_version=`getconf _POSIX_VERSION`
if test $ac_posix_version -ne 200809 >/dev/null 2>&1
  AC_MSG_FAILURE([POSIX.1-2008 profile required])
fi
```

This might have bugs (not tested). It's clearly of no use in cross compilation.

Comment: Which `CC` and `CFLAGS` does `AC_COMPILER_IFELSE` use?

Comment: @VilhelmGray - [`AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Running-the-Compiler) uses the `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, and `CC` variables, as described in (the link to) the [Language Choice](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Language-Choice) section.

Comment: I just realized that `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` may not solve what I had intended since a test program will use the default value set for `_POSIX_VERSION` if the implementation is capable of supporting multiple POSIX standards. Rather, I'm looking for if a specific POSIX standard is capable of being supported, so I need some way to portably grep the `unistd.h` file for the string `#define _POSIX_VERSION 200809L`.

Comment: Finally there's [sysconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sysconf.html). i.e., `if (sysconf(_SC_VERSION) >= 200809L) /* POSIX.1-2008 */

Comment: I found a way to make the `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` method work: add `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before the `#include <unistd.h>`. [This explicitly requests compliance to the **POSIX.1-2008** standard on the implementation.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_01_01)