# How do I test for GNU strftime extensions in autoconf?

Tags: glibc, autoconf, strftime

`strftime` is a standard Unix C function. The version of `strftime` in `glibc` supports some extensions. Using `autoconf`, is there an easy way to test whether `strftime` supports these extensions?

Failing that, is there an easy way in `autoconf` to test whether the standard library is the GNU `glibc`?

Comment: You cannot reliably test for all of the extensions in glibc (and musl and other implementations) since POSIX.1-2001 implementations would call them "undefined behavior". [POSIX.1-2008](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html) supports some (but not all) of the extensions. You can [use AC_EGREP_CPP to detect the POSIX version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18240603), and that will allow you to detect whether you can use the POSIX extensions or not.

Comment: The other option is to restrict your code to glibc only by checking whether `__GNU_LIBRARY__` or `__GLIBC__` are defined (you'll want to `#include <limits.h>` in your preprocessor test to get at least one of those macros defined), but that means musl and other implementations that support the features will not be able to use them since those implementations likely do not define either of those two glibc-specific preprocessor macros.